# No cipher suites in common java sockets

Tags: java, sockets, ssl

I have been using SSL sockets for a messaging system recently.

I finally started using a CA issued certificate. I imported it into my keystore, set the keystore property, and started up my client, but I keep getting handshake exceptions when I try to send data.

I enabled debug mode and I found that it is due to `no cipher suites supported`. Any thoughts on this?

If it helps, It also says that it is ignoring about 10 cipher suites from TLSV1 and TLSV1.1.

I also installed Unlimited Strength Cryptographic Policy.

**Client code**

```
public static void Message(String args){
    System.setProperty("https.protocols", "TLSv1");
    System.setProperty("javax.net.debug", "all");

    try
    {
        String host = "localhost";
        int port = 3498;
        InetAddress address = InetAddress.getByName(host);

        socket = (SSLSocket)SSLSocketFactory.getDefault().createSocket(address, port);

        //Send the message to the server
        OutputStream os = socket.getOutputStream();
        OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(os);
        BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(osw);

        String number = "Hello from the other side!";

        String sendMessage = number + "\n";
        bw.write(args);
        bw.flush();
        System.out.println("Message sent to the server : "+sendMessage);

        //Get the return message from the server

    }
    catch (Exception exception)
    {
        exception.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally
    {
        //Closing the socket
        try
        {
            socket.close();
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

**Server code**

```
private void initListen() {
    System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStore", "/Users/181095/server.jks");
    try {


        SSLServerSocketFactory sf = (SSLServerSocketFactory)SSLServerSocketFactory.getDefault();

        SSLServerSocket serverSocket = (SSLServerSocket)sf.createServerSocket(Ting.port);



        System.out.println("Server Started and listening to the port "
                + Ting.port);

        // Server is running always. This is done using this while(true)
        // loop
        while (true) {

            // Reading the message from the client
            socket = (SSLSocket)serverSocket.accept();


            InputStream is = socket.getInputStream();
            InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
            String input = br.readLine();
            System.out.println("Message received from client is " + input);
            /*if(PacketReader.isPacket(input)){
                if(PacketReader.shouldSendDataBack(input)){

                }
            }*/
            /*
             * 
             * if client has data waiting or client has new data
             * request new data.
             * else, wait 5 seconds and repeat
             * 
             * 
             */



            // Sending the response back to the client.
            /*OutputStream os = socket.getOutputStream();
            OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(os);
            BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(osw);
            bw.write("");*/

            //TODO Implement method to send this data to client storage data.

            //bw.flush();
        }
    //Check for exceptions and try to close the socket.
    } catch (Exception e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                socket.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
        }
    }
}
```

**Edit:**
I have just added the password, but my entry/certificate does not have a key, could this be contributing to the error? How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Surprisingly, this can mean that the server couldn't find a private key/certificate pair. In this case it is because you haven't specified the keystore password via `javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword`.

Comment: I did this but it still doesnt work, because I got the from an external source, do I need to set a key, because using keytool, it cannot find the key. Do I need to generate a key?

Comment: You can't 'get a [certificate] from an external source' and use it as your own certificate. You have to start by creating a key pair, then a CSR, then get it signed, then import the signed certificate into the same keystore with the same alias and without the `-trustcacerts` option.

Comment: Okay, so what I did was use the SSL from my website. My website is using the SSL. I downloaded the SSL certificate from the CSR I generated. This was done through NameCheap, and I believe they do it through Comodo SSL. I do not believe it came with a key as when I use keytool on it, it says there is no key. What is going on here?

Comment: There is no such thing as an 'SSL'. Do you mean 'SSL *certificate*'? It must have originated with a key. There is no other process.

Comment: Yup, turns out to be an issue with the NameCheap, they have not done it properly. Thanks